# What's the best way to create a Java EE project (maven+git) using Spring tool suite?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-tool-suite

I see that there are many kinds of project you can create with **Spring Tool Suite**.
I'm wondering what's the best choice if I should create a **Java Enterprise Edition** project, integrated with **maven** and **git**.

Is there a specific project to select, in order to have straight away all the environment ready?

Comment: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/07/spring-boot-project-sts.html

Comment: Thank you man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Spring perspective, I would strongly recommend to start with a Spring Boot project and go from there, using the new Spring Tools 4 (or the Spring Tool Suite version 4). It provides wizards to get started quite easily.

If you don't want to use Spring Boot, but something else from the Java Enterprise Edition standard in combination with Spring, I would recommend to use the Spring Tools 3 distribution (comes with the full Java EE tooling from Eclipse pre-installed) or install the necessary parts from Eclipse into a Spring Tools 4 installation. Which parts you need highly depends on which parts of the Java Enterprise Edition spec you would like to use - the general term "Java Enterprise Edition" is very broad and it is hard to give any advice without knowing which parts you would like to use or what you would like to accomplish.